# Changing field values using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor

I want to make my field buff_dist longer than by 400ft.  I want to write a code that will go through the table and change the field value by adding 400ft to it's value.

How would I write that?

I tried to use UpdateCursor, but I don't think I was understanding it. I also want to be able to select certain objects to change the buff_dist field of, but knowing how to change the field value is one step closer for me!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Field Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) (simple):

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Buffer_Field","!Buffer_Field!+400","PYTHON_9.3")
```

Or in ArcMap by opening the attribute table, right click on the *Buffer_Field* and then in the dialog enter `Buffer_Field + 400`.

Using update cursor (somewhat advanced):

```
import arcpy

InTable = "c:\\path\\to\\table" # or feature class

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(InTable,["Buffer_Field"]) as UpCur:
    for row in UpCur:
        row[0] = row[0] + 400
        UpCur.updateRow(row)
```

Note: this is bare bones code with no error checking for Null values or string field types, that gets a little more advanced.